# Why are JSON requests to my external API being cancelled in my Spotify App?

Tags: json, api, spotify

I'm building a Spotify App that pulls JSON data from a REST API, using URLs like

```
http://www.mydomain.com/api/command?option=value
```

In my Spotify app manifest I have set the required permissions for my API host:

```
"RequiredPermissions": [ "http://*.mydomain.com" ]
```

I have also configured Cross-Origin Resource Sharing in the response headers of my API. Here is a real example:

```
Server: nginx/0.7.65
Date: Thu, 08 Dec 2011 09:07:16 GMT
Content-Type: application/json
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: Mojolicious (Perl)
Set-Cookie: mojolicious=eyJwcmVmcyI6e30sImZpbHRlcnMiOnsicGllciI6eyJzb3VyY2VzIjpbMjBdfSwiZWxlYyI6eyJzb3VyY2VzIjpbMTMsMTddLCJ4dGFncyI6WyJzaG9lZ2F6ZSJdLCJ0YWdzIjpbImVsZWN0cm9uaWMiXX0sInB1bmtkdWIiOnsieHRhZ3MiOlsicmVnZ2FlIl0sInRhZ3MiOlsicHVuayIsImR1YiJdfX0sImV4cGlyZXMiOjEzMjMzMzg4MzZ9--c6d6214525b5d56785eebc99217394a1; Version=1; Path=/; expires=Thu, 08 Dec 2011 10:07:16 GMT
Content-Length: 23381
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *

200 OK
```

In Spotify, in the chrome inspector network tab, I see that the request is being cancelled:

```
Name: command www.mydomain.net/api 
Method: GET 
Status Text: (canceled) 
Type: undefined 
Initiator: jquery-1.js:7180 (Script) 
Size Content: 13B (0B) 
Time Latency: 21ms (0.0 days)
```

[image: Chrome inspector snapshot]

If I run my app in Chrome on my desktop (outside of Spotify) the request is not cancelled and all is good.

What am I doing wrong? Or maybe this is a bug (feature?) in Spotify preview release?

Comment: The first thing I would try to do is analyze the actual request being made by Spotify using a tool like Wireshark. Then you can verify that a) the Spotify app is sending a valid Origin header (which is required for CORS) and b) you can see any custom request headers sent by Spotify. Note that the CORS spec doesn't allow '*' as a value to the Access-Control-Allow-Headers header. I would recommend echoing back the parameters you receive in the Access-Control-Request-Headers.

Comment: I had the same problem and as monsur stated above, the Access-Control-Allow-Headers was the issue I had. I changed my server to set the header to "*" and it worked.

Comment: monsur - I'll try wireshark, but Chrome shows the outgoing request and there are no unusual headers.
slurmomatic - I already have allow-headers set to "*". Was your problem with Spotify?

Comment: Actually, I meant "Access-Control-Allow-Origin". When accessing my API previously I also got the canceled message. With Allow-Origin set to * it worked (of course I also had to set RequiredPermissions in the manifest).

Comment: It turns out my problem was with the manifest file - CORS was configured correctly - see below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A couple of things can cause this, I'll put them in order from easiest to resolve to hardest.

1. Check that you have the correct `RequiredPermissions` in your manifest.json
2. Check that your manifest.json has a valid json strjcture, you can do this on websites like http://jsonlint.com/
3. Make sure you're not storing the file with a BOM character (invisible byte at the start of the file), this can cause parsing of the manifest to fail
4. Make sure that the server you are querying accepts your origin. All apps in Spotify have an origin like `sp://appname`, most servers only accept http and https protocols by default, so you can set the `Acces-Control-Allow-Origin` to `*` to make sure the request doesn't get cancelled.

Lastly, I'd like to note that even though a request sometimes shows up in the inspector as cancelled, it'll still have a correct response, so be sure to double-check that as well.

Hope this helps!

Edit: sometimes, for some weird reason, it also helps to set the url you're requesting in `RequiredPermissions` without the `http://` or `https://` prepended.

Comment: Thanks for this checklist - the problem turned out to be a non-valid json structure in my manifest file.

Comment: For me it was both invalid json and not restarting the whole client that fuzzed.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried restarting Spotify to reload changes to `RequiredPermissions`? I used to have a similar problem that was resolved upon a restart.

Comment: +1 - I just had exactly the same problem as the OP, everything on Chiel's list checked out, restarting Spotify did the trick.

Answer (score 4):

Another thing to be wary of:

If you are doing local development.  Do **NOT** try to issue your ajax/getJSON calls to "localhost" or "127.0.0.1", **use your Eth/WiFI interface IP instead**.

The spotify web engine either blocks these localhost identifiers in requests, or the loopback interface is ignored, or windows has interfered again.

This may be apparent to some, but took me a while to figure it out.

Comment: I can attest that this is still a problem.  I'm getting hit by this at the "Music Apps Hack Weekend".  Should have hit SO sooner. :)

Answer (score 0):

Spotify uses Chromium inside and therefore adheres to the [Same Origin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) policy. To get around it, use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP). I'd recommend setting the origin policy on your webhost to only allow Spotify.

Comment: JSON P is one option, but Chrome also supports CORS

Answer (score 0):

The one causing my problem was the Bom character.

In order to fix that I used Notepad++, Encode -> Encode in UTF-8 without BOM